# Verificar se existe valor em JSON com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho uma variável que retorna um certo número que está correto.

**Exemplo:**

```
$cc = "52532005536430673";
```

A minha dúvida é: como faço para verificar se este número está presente em um JSON? Conforme abaixo:

```
{
    "testadas": {
        "52532005536430673|04|2023|869": {
            "cc": "52532005536430673",
            "dados": "\ud83c\udde7\ud83c\uddf7",
            "status": "Reprovada",
            "data_hora": "02-09-2018 20:45:13",
            "retestada": false
        }
    }
}
```

Neste caso ele está presente no "CC" e sempre quero verificar se o número está presente no "CC".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente, você pode converter esse json para um objeto ou array, e em seguida percorre-lo por todos os itens que estão no "testadas" fazendo uma verificação se o campo cc não é vazio.

No exemplo abaixo, converti o json para array, utilizando a função json_decode, e passei como primeiro parâmetro o json e o segundo o valor 1, que sinaliza que quero converter para array e não objeto.

```
$json = '{
"testadas": {
    "52532005536430673|04|2023|869": {
        "cc": "52532005536430673",
        "dados": "\ud83c\udde7\ud83c\uddf7",
        "status": "Reprovada",
        "data_hora": "02-09-2018 20:45:13",
        "retestada": false
    }
  }
}';

$resultado_json = json_decode($json,1);
$cartao = "52532005536430673";
foreach($resultado_json["testadas"] as $item){
  if($item["cc"] == $cartao){
    print "Numero presente no campo cc";
  }
}
```

Comment: Creio que isto não funcionaria corretamente, pois eu tenho varios campos cc no json, e preciso verificar da variavel!

Comment: Poderia mostrar um exemplo de um json que tem mais de um cc?

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/bfqpj
Seria basicamente isto!

Comment: Então, da forma que lhe apresentei ele está percorrendo cada item do json. Primeiro ele irá verificar se na chave "52532005536430673|04|2023|869" existe o campo cc, e em seguida, se na chave "52532005536400673|04|2023|869" existe esse campo nela. Não havendo problema de haver mais de um campo "cc", já que vai apenas validar o contexto de cada chave em cada item do json.

Comment: Ok, mas acaba occorendo o mesmo "erro" que falei para o Gabriel, o foreach não retorna nada!

Comment: O primeiro parametro do json_decode deve ser uma string e não um arquivo. Para pegar o valor que está no arquivo que deseja pode ser feito dessa forma:
json_decode(file_get_contents($file2),1);

Comment: Ok, consegui resolver, mas agora para eu dar um echo nas info, como os dados por exemplo, seria isto?: echo $item["$cartao"]->dados;

Comment: Seria assim: echo $item['dados']; , não será necessário passar a identificação do cartão para printar as outras colunas dentro do foreach.

Comment: Funcionou, valeu parceiro!
Agradecido!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está o código em funcionamento, ele pega o cc do JSON e depois compara com o valor da variável. Para pegar de um arquivo externo, é necessário que utilize `file_get_contents()` para pegar o link do JSON:

**Arquivo PHP:**

```
<?php
$cc = "52532005536430673";
$file = "ccs.json";

$json_file = file_get_contents($file);
$json_result = json_decode($json_file);

foreach($json_result->testadas as $item){
    if($item->cc == $cc){
        print "Esse número está presente em cc";
    }
    else{
        print "Esse número não está presente em cc";
    }
}
?>
```

**ccs.json**

```
{
    "testadas": {
        "52532005536430673|04|2023|869": {
            "cc": "52532005536430673",
            "dados": "\ud83c\udde7\ud83c\uddf7",
            "status": "Reprovada",
            "data_hora": "02-09-2018 20:45:13",
            "retestada": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/Mnu8Ek
Acabou ficando desta maneira, mas quando eu testo ele não retorna nada, e dei echo no $cartao e tudo, e está tudo correto!
Só que não retorna nada no foreach

Comment: editei o código, segundo o que você colocou no ideone, pegando o JSON de um arquivo. Testa agora e vê como fica o funcionamento.

Comment: Agora ele retornou, mas retornou os 2:
Esse número não está presente em ccEsse número está presente em cc
kk

Comment: estranho, não deveria entrar no if e no else ao mesmo tempo e acabei de executar o código aqui e está funcionando

Comment: https://ideone.com/CVu59f
Este é o codigo final, mas está retornando os 2

Comment: Ok, consegui resolver, mas agora para eu dar um echo nas info, como os dados por exemplo, seria isto?:
echo $item["$cartao"]->dados;

Comment: echo "<b>Dados:</b> ".$item->dados;

Comment: Não retornou nada!

Comment: Você está fazendo do jeito certo? Pois, segundo o código que você colocou no idone, ele está imprimindo tudo o que está escrito, não o resultado.

Comment: Consegui fazer conforme o codigo do Andre
echo $item['dados'];